# Index Match Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have two sheets and i want to use the index match combination via VBA.
Since the column name/order changes every time, i need to use the header name (first row) to identify each column. I have two worksheets (Fruit and Animal) in a single workbook.

I wrote the following VBA code to run a loop, but it fails:

```
    For i = 2 to 20

      worksheets("fruit").cells(i, D).Value = _
      worksheetfunction.index(worksheets("Animal").columns(animal_id), _
      worksheetfunction.match(worksheets("fruit").cells(i, fruit_id).value, _    
      worksheets("animal").columns(fruit_id_animal), 0))


   Next i
```

animal_id, fruit_id, i, fruit_id_animal are all integer column number. I even tried with `.range.cells`
rather than columns, but it still not working. The error shown is "Application-defined or object-defined error"/1004.

can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: `cells(i, "D")` maybe?  You're doing a lot in one line of code, so maybe break it up into multiple lines, and declare a couple of worksheet variables to avoid repetition like `worksheets("fruit")` etc.  Assuming all your variables such as `animal_id` etc have valid integer values.

Comment: Also, replace both occurrences of `worksheetfunction.` with `Application.`.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
For i = 2 to 20
    Worksheets("Fruit").Cells(i, "D").Value = _
        Application.Index(Worksheets("Animal").Columns(animal_id), _
        Applicatiion.Match(Worksheets("Fruit").Cells(i, fruit_id).Value, _    
        Worksheets("Animal").Columns(fruit_id_animal), 0))
Next i
```

**An Improvement (Standalone)**

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookupTest()
     
    ' Animal
    Const Fruit_ID_Animal As Long = 1
    Const Animal_ID As Long = 2
    ' Fruit
    Const Fruit_ID As Long = 1
    Const Animal_ID_Fruit As Long = 4
    Const Fruit_First_Row As Long = 2
    Const Fruit_Last_Row As Long = 20
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Animal")
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Columns(Fruit_ID_Animal)
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = sws.Columns(Animal_ID)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Fruit")
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(Fruit_First_Row, _
        Fruit_ID), dws.Cells(Fruit_Last_Row, Fruit_ID))
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(Animal_ID_Fruit)
    
    With Application
        drrg.Value = .Index(srrg, .Match(dlrg, slrg, 0))
    End With
       
End Sub
```